# simple way to call struts2 action

Tags: java, html, struts2

I need to test certain struts2 action classes in struts and I want to use just a regular old button. not necessarily a submit button, just a button. What would be the simplest way for me to tie an action class to a click event?

say I have a jsp page

```
<html>
 <head>

 </head>

 <body>

    <form>
      <button id="buttonId">imAButton /button>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

and an action class

```
public class ActionClass1 {

public String execute(){

    System.out.println("yes this test is juvenile but it works!");

      return "iWork";  
}}
```

Comment: post some code to understand your question more easy..

Comment: There are 1337 ways of doing this. Be more specific, post some code and more detailed requirements

Comment: Unclear what do you ask. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `<form>...</form>` in JSP page, give your action name in `action="..."` parameter in form tag element.

Write onclick function for button and submit your form in that function.

```
<form action="yourActionName" id="testForm">
    <!--other form elements-->
    <button name="btn" id="btn" onclick="myFunction()"></button>  
</form>  

<script>
    //Your JavaScript function.
    function myFunction()
    { 
       // submit your form here by JavaScript or JQuery.
       //by JavaScript  
       document.getElementById("testForm").submit();  

       //by JQuery  
       $("#testForm").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a form in your JSP and on clik, call javascript to submit it as shown below:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit()
```

You can also give it any action using script. That action should be mapped in struts configuration file.

Comment: so would that involve Jquery?